# How can I catch everything after the underscore in a filepath with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing

How can I catch everything after the last underscore in a filename?

ex: `24235235adasd_4.jpg` into `4.jpg`

Thanks again!

Comment: @Don, there are two answers with regexp and two without.  What more could you want? ;)

Comment: Should be "after the underscore" in the question title?

Comment: There are plenty of answers here.  Did you still have a question?

Answer (score 13):

```
var foo = '24235235adasd_4.jpg';
var bar = foo.substr(foo.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
```

*Make a note to yourself that this wont work with those uncommon files that have an '_' in their extension (for example, I've seen some that are named `filename.tx_`)

Comment: I had it wrapped in an `alert()` before and missed removing the closing `)` when I pasted the code. All fixed now :)

Answer (score 11):

```
var end = "24235235adasd_4.jpg".match(/.*_(.*)/)[1];
```

Edit: Whoops, the ungreedy modifier was wrong.

Edit 2:  After running a benchmark, this is the slowest method.  Don't use it ;)  Here is the benchmark and the results.

**Benchmark:**

```
var MAX     = 100000,     i =  0, 
    s       = new Date(), e = new Date(), 
    str     = "24235235ad_as___4.jpg",
    methods = {
        "Matching":  function() { return str.match(/.*_(.*)/)[1];               },
        "Substr":    function() { return str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);  },
        "Split/pop": function() { return str.split('_').pop();                  },
        "Replace":   function() { return str.replace(/.*_/,'');                 }
    };

console.info("Each method over %d iterations", MAX);
for ( var m in methods ) {
    if ( !methods.hasOwnProperty(m) ) { continue; }
    i = 0;

    s = new Date();
    do {
        methods[m]();
    } while ( ++i<MAX );
    e = new Date();

    console.info(m);
    console.log("Result: '%s'", methods[m]());
    console.log("Total: %dms; average: %dms", +e - +s, (+e - +s) / MAX);
}
```

**Results:**

```
Each method over 100000 iterations
Matching
Result: '4.jpg'
Total: 1079ms; average: 0.01079ms
Substr
Result: '4.jpg'
Total: 371ms; average: 0.00371ms
Split/pop
Result: '4.jpg'
Total: 640ms; average: 0.0064ms
Replace
Result: '4.jpg'
Total: 596ms; average: 0.00596ms
```

[Gordon Tucker's Substr/lastIndexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799543/how-to-catch-everything-before-the-underscore-in-a-filepath-with-javascript/1799586#1799586) is the fastest by a long shot.

Comment: Different JavaScript/ECMAScript implementations will perform this benchmark differently. Out of curiosity which engine was used for the results here? It would be really interesting to see if there was any variation in results on other engines. Thanks for taking the time to do this!

Comment: Total MS for 100000
Matching, Substr, Split/pop, Replace

**IE 8**
`538, 118, 427, 336;`

**FF 3.5.5**
`221, 18, 62, 119;`

**Chrome 4.0.223.16**
`57, 27, 152, 35;`

**Safari 530.17**
`135, 52, 55, 42;`

**Opera 10.10**
`258, 152, 156, 402;`

Comment: My test was on FF 3.5.5/OS X 10 .5.8

Answer (score 9):

```
"24235235adasd_4.jpg".split('_').pop();
```

Comment: +1 for most readable code, and for allowing input with *no* underscores

Comment: Readable yes, but all other responses besides my own work with or without underscores.

Answer (score 0):

```
var end = filename.replace(/.*_/,'');
```